# How to implement barcode scanner functionality in ios?

Tags: ios4, cordova, xcode4.3, phonegap-plugins

already i have built bar-code scanner app in android using phone-gap,now i want to implement same thing in ios also,i want use same java script,css files for this ios app also. Give me suggestions how to start i'm new to ios development.suggest me a library that runs on present ios mobiles like iphone 3gs,4...etc.

Answer (score 0):

hi use barcode scanner plugin for IOS  [link](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iOS/BarcodeScanner)